# Default localisation

Tags: localisation

Can you please tell me if you can set the default localisation to one country, so that language/currency/address country are already set?

Many thanks

Paul

Comment: Can you clarify your question and perhaps give an example of what you want to achieve? It will improve your chance of getting a helpful answer.

Answer (score 4):

Defaults for localisation you can set :

Go to,

CiviCRM->Administer->Localization->Language,Currency,Locations

You can set,

a) Preferred languages Options
b) Date formats
c) Addresses settings under   Administer menu.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a single localisation per country, but per civicrm installation.

The various defaults you can set (eg language, currency, list of available countries, date format...) are in various screens under the administer menu.

We tried to group them more based on the feature you try to set rather than based on the region it's used because you can have different "locale" settings within the same country (eg the default language can be french or english in Canada), or have a us-english language, use euro as the default currency and dd-mm-yyyy as the date format...

After an installation, you have a list of the most common settings you'd want to adjust, it should cover the localisation items you want to tune.